# I want to check/count if two lists have at-least one element common in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

for example:

list_1 = (a, b, c)

list_2 =(z,a,x)

result= 1

Comment: Do an inner join.

Answer (score 2):

If you define a list:

```sql
CREATE TYPE char_list AS TABLE OF CHAR(1);
```

Then you can use `MULTISET` operators to find the `INTERSECT`ion:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN char_list('a', 'b', 'c')
            MULTISET INTERSECT char_list('z', 'a', 'x')
            IS NOT EMPTY
       THEN 'True'
       ELSE 'False'
       END AS has_intersection
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | HAS_INTERSECTION |
> | --- |
> | True |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=93f2f2ab45137d92aedba2ee06167bda)*